# Documentation of Gazebo topics

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Are the default Gazebo topics documented anywhere? Searches on Google and Gazebo answers turned up nothing. The documentation on gazebosim.org only covers the code API and protobuf messages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16635/documentation-of-gazebo-topics/) by [yamokosk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/69/yamokosk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-07-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Unfortunately, I don't think there is any documentation on Gazebo topics, that would definitely be good to have.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1